# Is there any way to update QTY programmatically using front controller?

Tags: magento, magento2

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);

$productStockData = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId()); 

$productStockData->setData('is_in_stock', 0);

$productStockData->setData('qty', 0);

$productStockData->setData('manage_stock', 1);

$productStockData->save();

echo "<pre>";

print_r($productStockData->getData());

exit;

$product->save();
```

This code gives the correct result with qty in array print but not reflecting in database ..

when it ry to print product data then it return `qty` 0 (Zero)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPenh.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use following code for set stock data. Reference [Click Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102922/programmatically-create-a-simple-product-in-magento-2%20Click%20Here)

```
$productStockData->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
        'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
        'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
        'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        'qty' => 1 //qty
        )
    );
```